# How do I make a table filter through one dataset when loaded but a different one while searching in React?

Tags: reactjs, html-table

**Situation:**

1. I have a table that loads in userData
2. When the user types into the table's search bar, it fires a change event that hits a search function
3. The search function iterates through the s and s for what the user is looking for and hides the stuff they aren't
4. When the user backspaces all the searched characters away, it unhides everything

**The Code:**

*Search Feature:*

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
```

*The Table*

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
         {userDataA.map(key, value) {
             <td>{value}</td>
             <td>{key}</td>
         })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The Question:**

How do I make the tablebody filter through one dataset when it loads and a **different** dataset while searching?

For example, when the page loads, I want it to filter through the data in UserDataA. When It searches, I want the table to filter through userDataB.

**Okay that's stupid and easy, why don't you just use a variable?**

...Because it doesn't work. I've tried it multiple different ways.

**JSX conditional based on a boolean**

```
  <tbody>
         {searchIsPerformed === true ? dataToReadFrom = userDataB : userDataA}
         {dataToReadFrom.map(key, value) {
             <td>{value}</td>
             <td>{key}</td>
         })}
  </tbody>
```

This just tells me dataToReadFrom is null and the page won't load.

*So I tried doing it with state.*

const [dataToReadFrom, setDataToReadFrom] = useState(userDataA);

If I instantiate useState with userDataA, it throws ReactError 301. If I leave it blank and try to set it manually below, the table doesn't render.

I feel like this is a stupidly easy question and I'm missing something.

Comment: Where are you setting `searchIsPerformed`? Have you tried moving this conditional out of your JSX and into a useEffect that sets `dataToReadFrom` whenever `searchIsPerformed` changes?

Comment: This is actually one of the 9 other things I tried. For some reason I can't get the data to dynamically display in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Could you include the code where `searchIsPerformed` is being set? This could be useful.